# Multi language on static website with i18next client side

Tags: javascript, static, multilingual, i18next

I made a website with HTML, CSS and Javascript without using a CMS, so it's all kind of static. I've been asked to make this project into a multi language website (the current language and English). Now I am looking for a good way to implement all the translations.

I've seen a simple solution with i18next using client-side Javascript, but I'm wondering if this isn't harmful for SEO (the url doesn't change when selecting another language) and if there is a better solution for this.

https://github.com/dwkns/i18next-translation-tutorial

Comment: the link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Hidden content may not be read by the search engines. It's better to have two versions of entire site in subfolders. 
If you really want to do it with javascript, try to put both content visible in html (users with no javascript should see both) and then with javascript hide one of them after page loading. But i suggest the first approach, it's more realiable.

source about google do this: https://www.freshegg.co.uk/blog/technical-seo/google/how-does-google-treat-hidden-content

Answer (score 0):

No issue with that. Google and other search engines run javascript as user browsers. Just add some links so google could discover the pages in other language (not only have autodetection)

The only drawback you have currently are routes are not translated but that could be solved, eg. https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware#add-localized-routes

Comment: Even in 2021 it takes forever to index dynamically generated websites. If SEO is a real concern it's always safer to stick to SSR.